# Como fazer um "Case When" quando a condição é chamada uma Package com a função e Passado os Parâmetros?

Tags: mysql, sql, pl-sql

Estou tentando fazer uma modificação na Query sem destruir uma logica já feita.

Query Original:

```
IF Pcoluman = 'aceito' THEN
            if  (v_respon_alg = 'Y')
             OR (v_respon_las = 'Y')
             OR (v_respon_nye = 'Y')
             OR (v_respon_vav = 'Y') THEN
                 package_thea.validador('Nova York', 433);
                 package_thea.validador('Boston', 574);
                 package_thea.validador('Nova Jersey', 397);
        ELSE

                 package_thea.validador('Sem Registro Cidade', 000);
        END IF;
```

O que eu preciso fazer é colocar um case when no primeiro validador onde quando o v_res_pn_vav = 'Y' ele substitui para "Seattle".

Porem esta dando erro de posição, isso daria certo? ele fala que falta ";" dps fala que falta o END, depois cai no ELSE com erro, não estou conseguindo acertar.

Segue QUERY com modificação:

```
IF Pcoluman = 'aceito' THEN
            if  (v_respon_alg = 'Y')
             OR (v_respon_las = 'Y')
             OR (v_respon_nye = 'Y')
             OR (v_respon_vav = 'Y') THEN
                 CASE WHEN (v_respon_vav = 'Y') THEN package_thea.validador('Seattle', 8974) ELSE package_thea.validador('Nova York', 433); END
                 package_thea.validador('Boston', 574);
                 package_thea.validador('Nova Jersey', 397);
        ELSE

                 package_thea.validador('Sem Registro Cidade', 000);
        END IF;
```

No que estou errando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESOLUÇÃO DO PROBLEMA:**

Acabei descobrindo, eu fiz o seguinte:

```
IF Pcoluman = 'aceito' THEN
        if  (v_respon_alg = 'Y')
         OR (v_respon_las = 'Y')
         OR (v_respon_nye = 'Y')
         OR (v_respon_vav = 'Y') THEN
             package_thea.validador(CASE WHEN (v_respon_vav = 'Y') THEN 'Seatle' ELSE 'Nova York', END, 
                CASE WHEN (v_respon_vav = 'Y') THEN 8974 ELSE 433 END); 
             package_thea.validador('Boston', 574);
             package_thea.validador('Nova Jersey', 397);
    ELSE

             package_thea.validador('Sem Registro Cidade', 000);
    END IF;
```

Coloquei o Case When dentro do meu validadora e coloquei a condição, e nisso fazendo a simples substituição por dentro.

Vou deixar aqui caso alguém um dia tenha essa mesma dificuldade.

Mas isso resolveu meu problema

Comment: Se alguem conseguir validar essa resposta ficarei grato